# Flutter UI Complex Design

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Need to update my UI code below to create image button curves of product details and product features like the example, [UI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLluf.png).

```
   Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
     child: Visibility(
      visible: isVisible &&
          product.mainProductList!.productDetail!.isNotEmpty,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        child: Container(
          width: kScreenWidth(context) * 0.45,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: CustomText(
              text: product.mainProductList!.productDetail,
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              color: normalTextColour,
              fontSize: size14),
        ),
      ),
    ))
```

Here's how my result looks so far, [my sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaS45.png).

Comment: Please add codes that you have tried so far.

Comment: I have attached the code of flutter please have look in it.

Answer (score 0):

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: UITest()));
}

class UITest extends StatefulWidget {
  const UITest({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UITest> createState() => _UITestState();
}

class _UITestState extends State<UITest> {
  List<int> widgetIds = [0, 1];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: widgetIds.reversed
            .map((id) => StackItem(
                  id: id,
                  isTop: id == widgetIds.first,
                  text: id == 0 ? 'Product Details' : 'Product Features',
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      widgetIds = [widgetIds.last, ...widgetIds.getRange(0, 1)];
                    });
                  },
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StackItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int id;
  final bool isTop;
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  const StackItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.id,
    required this.isTop,
    required this.text,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: id * (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: isTop ? null : onTap,
        child: Container(
          height: 64,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: isTop ? Colors.green : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.25),
            shape: const MessageBorder(),
          ),
          child: Center(child: Text(text)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessageBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  final bool usePadding;

  const MessageBorder({this.usePadding = true});

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions =>
      EdgeInsets.only(bottom: usePadding ? 20 : 0);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    rect = Rect.fromPoints(rect.topLeft, rect.bottomRight - const Offset(0, 20));
    return Path()
      ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
        rect,
        topLeft: const Radius.circular(20),
        topRight: const Radius.circular(20),
      ))
      ..moveTo(rect.bottomRight.dx, rect.bottomRight.dy)
      ..relativeLineTo(20, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(rect.bottomRight.dx, rect.bottomRight.dy,
          rect.centerRight.dx, rect.centerRight.dy)
      ..close()
      ..moveTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx, rect.bottomLeft.dy)
      ..relativeLineTo(-20, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx, rect.bottomLeft.dy,
          rect.centerLeft.dx, rect.centerLeft.dy);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Bro i need border as well with it

Comment: I just gave you the code to point you in the right direction, sorry but I can't find enough time to complete the design.

Comment: Actually I was aware about the curve but i am having problem with curve radius with curve border.